# Proving the fundamental period of tangent

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, periodic-functions

I'm very new to math and proofs -- so I apologize if my math skills and vocabulary offends you.

I have a question that states:
Prove that $\pi$ is a fundamental period of the tangent function.

I need to know if the proof I wrote is adequate, here is my proof:

$a$ is a Real Number.
$0 < a < \pi$

$tan(s+a) = tan(s)$

The only case in which $tan(s) = 0$ is when:

$k$ is an Integer.
$tan(\pi * k) = 0 $

thus, 
$tan(a) != 0$

Because $tan$ is the ratio of an angle $\theta$ of $sin/cos$
and because $sin$ and $cos$ are ratios of sides of a triangle in reference to the unit circle and since the unit circle has a radius of $1$ and a circumference of $2\pi$ radians, in order for periodicity to occur, the period of tan must be $(\pi * k)$, where the arc length can never be a multiple of $\pi/2$

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Solve
$$\tan(t)=\tan(t+T).$$

You have

$$\tan(t+T)=\frac{\tan(t)+\tan(T)}{1-\tan(t)\tan(T)}=\tan(t),$$ and for $\tan(t)\tan(T)\ne1$,

$$\tan(T)=-\tan^2(t)\tan(T).$$

This is possible only when $\tan(T)=0$, for which the smallest positive solution is

$$T=\pi.$$

Comment: But what if you are only allowed to use given information, not including knowledge about $tan(pie)$?

Comment: @xatabay: use a pie chart then.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly true that $\tan(x +\pi) = \tan x$, so $\pi$ is at least a multiple of the period. Can you show that no smaller number will do? **Hint:** What is the slope of $\tan$ between $\pm \pi/2$?