# How many solutions exist for the equation $2\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{3}$ in $[0,2\pi]$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How many solutions exist for the equation $2\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{3}$ in $[0,2\pi]$ ?

All I could till now :
LHS =$2\sin{x}+\cos{x}$
Since, $−\sqrt{5} \leq 2\sin{x}+\cos{x} \leq \sqrt{5}$

So a solution must exist.  But how many?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)=c\sin(x+x_0)$.

In order to derive the new coefficients:

$c\sin(x+x_0)=c\sin(x)\cos(x_0)+c\sin(x_0)\cos(x)=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$

Compare coefficients: $A=c\cos(x_0)$ and $B=c\sin(x_0)$. Divide the equations.
$B/A=\tan(x_0)$ and square and add both equations $A^2+B^2=c^2$.

Hence, $c=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\sqrt{5}$ and $x_0=\arctan(B/A)=\arctan(1/2)$

Comment: Always amazing to see an accepted answer that does not answer the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: What do you mean? I simply used this as a hint. Using this knowledge it is easy to explicitly calculate the solutions and check, if they lie in the region.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the Hint tag. I am editing to be allowed to upvote.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a really neat geometric approach: Consider that $(x_1, x_2) = (\cos(x), \sin(x))$ traces a circle once, and that $2x_1+x_2=\sqrt{3}$ is a linear equation. The answers correspond to the intersections of a line with a circle.

Since the line passes through the interior of the circle, but not through $(1, 0)$ (which is mapped twice by the parametric description), there are exactly two such intersections.

Comment: This is MrYouMath solution, how and why it works, explained in just 1 line. I really like this.

Comment: Extremely elegant and a nice alternate to the usual solutions. +1

Answer (score 0):

let $\tan \theta=\frac12$, we have
$$\sin(x+\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos\theta$$, as a result
$$x=-\theta+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos\theta\right)$$
$$x=\pi+\theta-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos\theta\right)$$

Comment: How do you prove the first "identity" ?

Comment: we should not say solutions with theirs details.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Weierstrass Substitution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Weierstrass_Substitution),

if $\tan\dfrac x2=u,$ $$(\sqrt3+1)u^2-4u+\sqrt3-1=0$$

As the discriminant  $$4^2-4(\sqrt3-1)(\sqrt3+1)=8>0$$ there are two distinct real solutions.

Now using [Proving the fundamental period of tangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660100/proving-the-fundamental-period-of-tangent),  there will be exactly one solution for each  value of $u$ in $$0\le\dfrac x2\le\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

By the identity $a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)=A\sin(t+\phi)$ the LHS is a sinusoid hence there are two solutions in a period (supplementary angles) as we are in a case with $0<\left|\dfrac{RHS}A\right|<1$.