# tangent periodicity

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, periodic-functions

We have $\tan(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$. I was wondering why $\tan(x+{\pi/2})=\tan(x)$?

I wanted to Show

$$\frac{\sin(x+\pi/2)}{\cos(x+\pi/2)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\iff\frac{\sin(x+\pi/2)\cos(x)}{\cos(x+\pi/2)\sin(x)}=1\iff\frac{\cos^2(x)}{-\sin^2(x)}=1$$

But this would imply that $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=0$. But this is false

On the other hand we have that $$\tan(x+{\pi/2})=\tan(x)$$

don't we?

Comment: The period of $\tan$ is $\pi$, not $\pi/2$. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660100/proving-the-fundamental-period-of-tangent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since $\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)=1$, whereas $\tan\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\pi4\right)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

No.

$$\tan(x+\pi/2)=\frac{\sin(x+\pi/2)}{\cos(x+\pi/2)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin x\cos \pi/2 + \cos x \sin \pi/2}{\cos x \cos \pi/2 - \sin x \sin \pi/2}$$
$$=\frac{\cos x}{-\sin x}$$
$$=-\cot x$$

which is generally not equal to $\tan x$.

The period of $\tan x$ is $\pi$. A similar line of reasoning as above shows that
$$\tan  (x + \pi/2) = \frac{-\sin x}{-\cos x} = \tan x.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't. The real relation is
$$\tan\bigl(x+\tfrac\pi 2\bigr)=-\cot x=-\frac 1{\tan x}$$
since $\;\sin\bigl(x+\frac\pi 2)=\cos x$, whereas $\;\cos\bigl(x+\frac\pi 2\bigr)=\color{red}-\sin x$.

What is true is that $\tan x$ has period $\pi$, simply because
$$\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x,\quad\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos x.$$